# Django modelform: exclude fields by regex

Tags: django-forms

I have a "Villa" Model with lots of descriptive TextFields. For each TextField, I have a copy which will be the Russian translation of the original field, which I'm naming by appending "_ru", for example "long_description" and "long_description_ru". I would like to exclude all the "_ru" fields from my ModelForm, which I thought I would be able to do like this:

```
class VillaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Villa
        exclude = []
        for field_name in Villa.__dict__:
            print field_name
            if field_name.endswith("_ru"):
                exclude.append(field_name)
```

However, `Villa.__dict__` does not contain the TextFields - even though they get rendered by the ModelForm. Am I being very stupid here?

Answer (score 2):

I see it's been a while since you asked this but I have an answer for you.  I think this might be easier to do in the `__init__` function:

```
class VillaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Villa

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(VillaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field_name in self.fields.keys():
            if field_name.endswith("_ru"):
                del self.fields[field_name]
```

The code is not entirely tested but I do think it's easier to do in the `__init__` vs. in the Meta definition.